# Create a dynamic link in a PRD report

Tags: pentaho

How can I create a dynamic link in a report (PRD 3.9.1)?. It should redirect to a URL that is contained in a parameter (`urlParam = http://www.google.com`) or in a properties file that changes frequently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use a formula for the url.  use =[urlParam] to access the param directly, or you can add additional bits and build up the string if you need to.